# How to make comboBox as Editable in UWP?

Tags: xaml, uwp

Is there any property available to make comboBox as Editable in UWP. Please share your opinion.

Comment: Please tell what you mean by *editable*. Also it would be nice to show what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the `AutoSuggestBox` instead, although this doesn't behave exactly like an editable `ComboBox`

Answer (score 1):

Use `IsEditable="True"` property in ComboBox

Answer (score 0):

UWP ComboBox is not editable. You can chose items only through drop down.
Instead you can try with [Syncfusion's SfComboBox](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/uwp/combo-box).

Comment: $1000 is a bit too much for me to spend on a free UWP application.