# How to make AutoSuggestBox only allow "accepted" text selected from ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to prevent a C#/UWP AutoSuggestionBox from having text in the Box from a submitted search that was not found in the ItemsSource list.  If the Search is not found, I want the input focus to be impossible to remove from the AutoSuggestionBox until the problem is corrected by selecting a valid entry from the ItemsSource list, or by automatically picking the closest match in the list,  or by the user clicking the "x" to clear the search.  Only until these conditions are matched will the focus be allowed to be removed from the AutoSuggestionBox.

Here's the Effect i'm going for.  This is a clip of a ComboBox from an Access Database:

[image: Combobox with autocompletion]

Notice that it automatically selects the closest match in the list, and scrolls to it, and completes the text after the cursor using the match...

Any ideas on how to do this or something similar using AutoSuggestionBox?

Comment: Just did a search on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37693230/how-to-make-combobox-as-editable-in-uwp

Comment: Apparently, UWP ComboBox doesn't support an IsEditable Property.

Comment: I missed 'UWP' here. Have you thought of making custom control! that would be in your control how strict it should act on user input

Comment: That's an interesting idea.... I was thinking about adding a Textbox that's not editable, and poping up a Listbox inside of a ContentDialog when you click on textbox, Then somehow writing the selection back to the uneditable textbox after closing the ContentDialog

Comment: Or you can simply use [Auto Complete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/auto-suggest-box) property of textbox and in KeyUp event of it write logic to prevent invalid input. see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50154794/3901530) here i had handled keyUp event. what you need to do in that to check textbox's text with available options, if doesn't match trim lastly added character (like i have trimmed ',' there)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative Solution, Popup A dialogbox to create similar function. XAML as follows:

```
<ContentDialog ...
    x:Class="MyApp1.ContentDialog1"
    x:Name="A1Dialog"
    Title="MyDialog"
    DefaultButton="Primary"
    PrimaryButtonText="Ok"
    SecondaryButtonText="Cancel"
    Loaded="ContentDialog_Loaded"
    PrimaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick"
    SecondaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_SecondaryButtonClick">

<Grid Name="A1Grid" 
      Height="{Binding ElementName=A1Dialog, Path=ActualHeight}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox Name="A1TextBox" Grid.Row="0" 
         PlaceholderText="Search String" 
         TextChanged="A1TextBox_TextChanged"/>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1"
       ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
       VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox Name="A1ListBox" MinHeight="200"/>
    </ScrollViewer>

    </Grid>
</ContentDialog>
```

C# Backing XAML as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public sealed partial class ContentDialog1 : ContentDialog
{
    List<string> Choices = new List<string>
    {
            "One", "Two", "Three", "Four",
            "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight",
            "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve",
            "13", "14", "15", "16",
            "17", "18", "19",
            "20"
    };

    public ContentDialog1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        A1ListBox.ItemsSource = Choices;
        this.IsPrimaryButtonEnabled = false;
    }

    private void A1TextBox_TextChanged(
        object sender, 
        TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.IsPrimaryButtonEnabled = false;
        string text = A1TextBox.Text;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            A1ListBox.ItemsSource = Choices;
        }
        else
        {
            string search = text.ToLower();
            List<string> list = Choices.Where(
                    x => x.ToLower().Contains(search))
                    .ToList();

            A1ListBox.ItemsSource = list;
            if (list.Count != 0)
            {
                this.IsPrimaryButtonEnabled = true;
                A1ListBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }

    }

    // OK Button
    private void ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick(
         ContentDialog sender, 
         ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs args)
    {
    }

    // Cancel Button
    private void ContentDialog_SecondaryButtonClick(
          ContentDialog sender, 
          ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs args)
    {
    }

    private void ContentDialog_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

}
```

From method opening DialogBox:

```
async void Click(sender s, …) {
    var D = new ContentDialog1();
    ContentDialogResult Result = await D.ShowAsync();
    switch(Result) {
        // Ok Button
        case ContentDialogResult.Primary:
            // this might require a little bit of fixing
            // to save result in public variable...
            // because A1ListBox is not public visible...
            // but the idea is similar...
            var SelectedItem = D.A1ListBox.SelectedItem;
            DoSomethingOk();
            break;
        // Cancel Button
        case ContentDialogResult.Seconday:
            DoSomethingCancel();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have resolved your issue please [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) it as accepted to convenient people who visit this thread later, Thanks for understanding.